# python parse from a json array with duplicate names (mitre att&ck)

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am a novice trying to parse data from a repo of mitre att&ck json files and am stuck on how to parse data for one of the fields - attack phase names. They are stored in an array and there are sometimes duplicate names, see below:

```
"type": "attack-pattern",
            "kill_chain_phases": [
                {
                    "kill_chain_name": "mitre-attack",
                    "phase_name": "persistence"
                },
                {
                    "kill_chain_name": "mitre-attack",
                    "phase_name": "privilege-escalation"
                }
            ],
```

If I try to return values for `get_phase(attack.kill_chain_phases[0].phase_name)`, python only returns one value when there are sometimes multiple values, like `privilege-escalation`

If I try to mess around and use something like this `get_phase(attack.kill_chain_phases[0].phase_name[0])` the output is the first character of one of the phase names `c`

If I try to do something like `get_phase(attack_pattern.kill_chain_phases[1].phase_name)` I get an out of index error...

Does anyone have an idea on how I can go about using python to grab these fields? Also does anyone know how to describe this data format and/or what I'm trying to do so I can try to search for solutions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop). A simple example would be something like:

```
for attack in attack_pattern.kill_chain_phrases:

    get_phrase(attack)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a loop for this. Get the parent of the items you want to find all the values for, and then you can loop through and get all the children's values.

```
import json

json_string = """{
  "type": "attack-pattern",
  "kill_chain_phases": [
    {
      "kill_chain_name": "mitre-attack",
      "phase_name": "persistence"
    },
    {
        "kill_chain_name": "mitre-attack",
        "phase_name": "privilege-escalation"
    }
  ]
}
"""

parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

# Loop through the parent "kill_chain_phases"
for kill_chain_phase in parsed_json["kill_chain_phases"]:
  # print out the children "phase_name" values
  print(kill_chain_phase["phase_name"]
```

You get the first character for `get_phase(attack.kill_chain_phases[0].phase_name[0]` because:
`get_phase(attack.kill_chain_phases[0].phase_name[0]` = "persistence"

Python then takes that string and treats it like a list:
["p", "e", "r", "s", "i", "s", "t", "e", "n", "c", "e"]

So `phase_name[0]` will show `"p"`.

Hope that makes sense.

More info [here](https://realpython.com/python-json/)

Comment: thanks for the additional explanation and examples, this makes a lot of sense. I'm excited to try this out!

Comment: No problem, and if you are satisfied with one of the answers here on stack overflow mark an answer for other users to find the help they are looking for.

Comment: i'm likely doing something wrong here - I had to rewrite this to work with results from my stix2 filter. Still when I try to rewrite my function as a for loop, I get an attribute error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'phase_name'

```
def get_phase(killchain, phase_name):
    for phase_name in killchain:
        return(phase_name)
```
and
```
get_phase(attack_pattern.kill_chain_phases, attack_pattern.kill_chain_phases.phase_name)
```

Comment: @cookiesmonster14 I think it has to do with how the Json string is coming in. What do you get when you print `json_string` out? Are you going to be pulling it in from a file or from a web url?
print(json_string)

Comment: @cookiesmonster14 I just tried it again. I got that error the first time I ran it, and then it disappeared. Not sure why that's happening... 
If you can edit your post and add the code that you're having issues with I could help you more.

Comment: @cookiesmonster14 I also found this article for you. It talks about that error at the end.
https://blog.softhints.com/python-json-tutorial-for-beginners/